# Laravel - how to protect /public/files/uploads/ from web acces by customers

Tags: laravel

I've got a question. 
the admin and employee can upload stuff into `/public/files/uploads/`
and the customers are only allowed to see a part of the files in uploads.
but when I login as customer and visit: `/public/files/uploads/`
I can open and view every file.

I would like to know how to protect this from customers, like when they try to open `/public/files/uploads/` they redirect back to the home view.

This would need some sort of `.htaccess` but I can't seem to figure out how to get it working.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there htaccess files in other directories that restrict access? I think there is (if my memory serves me correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put an empty `index.html` file in this folder.

Also, are your normal URLs contain `public`? If so, you have wrong web server configuration and you should point your web server (Apache, Nginx) to a `public` directory instead of Laravel project's root folder.

Comment: Upvoted for the config suggestion as I'd imagine a few people may miss this

Comment: I'm using MAMP and sometimes working with multiple sites at the same time. Thanks for suggesting this tho!

Comment: @JordyGroote You can work with multiple sites and still point the server to specific directories. It's done in the `httpd.conf` file, check out [this](http://serverfault.com/a/146551) answer on how to do it.

Comment: AH, i didnt know that! Thanks @camelCase. Will use this for following projects

Comment: Putting the empty index.HTML into the directory worked also. Thanks alot!